# How do you render an image (from cloudinary) from strapi using NuxtJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, strapi, nuxtjs3

I'm fetching some data from the Strapi CMS which contains all info about the content in the cms. I'm trying to use the data to render an image(cloudinary provider) in my nuxt web app, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Refused to load the image '(url goes here)' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".
```

My image contains the link to the image, but the image is not rendering

```
<img class="h-28 w-28 rounded-full border-4 border-black bg-gray-300" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/diglwbyf0/image/upload/v1680679242/20220802_161149_732ed0aa85.jpg" alt="">
```

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CSP rule to allow images from Cloudinary: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

The CSP rule currently only allows images to be loaded from your domain and from inline images.

The first thing I would look at is who is setting the CSP rule for your project? Someone is setting the rule `"img-src 'self' data:"`.